# How does one find out the general solution of this second order differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble attacking this second order differential equation:

$$y''-tP(t)y'+P(t)y=0$$

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any info regarding $P$?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Variable coefficients.... P is a function of t. Other than that, we've been given nothing. I am clueless as to how to approach it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach:** What about the simple function $y_1(t)=t$? From there, you can find $y_2.$

Comment: How can you find $y_2$ from there? Imposing the wronskian equal to zero?

Comment: @Nivalth : Use [reduction of order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order). you cannot get an explicit answer since $P(t)$ is not given.

Comment: Yes....I'm kicking myself for not noticing that before :P
Thanks a lot!